# Copying files from a Foundry dataset to another Foundry dataset

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have two Foundry datasets that contain raw files (lets say xml or csv files). I would like to merge these two within a transform to create a new dataset with a collection from both.

(This explicit example was due to a API schema being updated, and required to merge the existing data with the new version).

ex
A: csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4, csv5 (source)
B: csv1, csv2, csv3 (target)

Answer (score 4):

Because Foundry datasets store raw files, a simple Python transform using shutil.copyfileobj should do the trick. This is further documented under Palantir docs: transforms/python-raw-file-access#writing-files

```py
for file_status in in_source.filesystem().ls(glob='*.csv'):
    with in_source.filesystem().open(file_status.path, 'rb') as in_f:
        with out.filesystem().open(file_status.path, 'wb') as out_f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(in_f, out_f)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).